# Security rules dont cascade like the docs said

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

The security rules dont cascade, like the docs says.

[image: Shallow rules dont override deeper rules]

This picture demonstrates the result of an authorized read request to path `/foo/baz/bar/` done with the simulator.

The Firebase Docs says this (code example is relevant to the docs):

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "foo": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    }
  }
}
```

> .read and .write rules cascade, so this ruleset grants read access to
> any data at path /foo/ as well as any deeper paths such as
> /foo/bar/baz. Note that .read and .write rules shallower in the
> database override deeper rules, so read access to /foo/bar/baz would
> still be granted in this example even if a rule at the path
> /foo/bar/baz evaluated to false.

Why do i get the opposite effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Allowing* access cascades, *denying* access does not. If denying access had the same cascading effect, rules would become verbose since you would have to explicitly exclude every part of the database you *don't* want affected even when denying.

Think of rules as a big or statement -- it goes through each matching rule one by one until it finds a `true`:

```
rule1 || rule2 || rule3 || rule4 ...
```

Comment: I thought all the rules cascaded, not *allow* specifically. Now i understand the rules as a whole better - and yes, it does help alot to think of the rules as a big OR statement.

I believe this information regarding the cascading effect only applying to the *allow* rule is not available in the docs - if not, how did you find out?

Comment: I work on Firebase and have had many years of experience with the system, so I don't remember how I originally found out but it sounds like there's an opportunity to improve our docs! :)

Comment: That's pretty cool, i must say its pretty neat that such a high quality service offers a free plan. Anyways, it would be greatly appreciated if the docs were explicit about this info. :)